# How to access url from another origin? Preflight request returns 401 even if Access-Control-Allow-* headers is present

Tags: java, cors, jetty, embedded-jetty

I run simple Jersey REST endpoint in embedded jetty with basic authentication and try to access it via ajax call from other web-application. But I get *401 Unauthorized* on preflight request even if Access-Control-Allow-* headers is present.

Server code:

```
public final class RESTServerStarter {
private static final int WEB_SERVER_PORT = 8888;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
    sh.setInitParameter(ServletContainer.RESOURCE_CONFIG_CLASS, PackagesResourceConfig.class.getCanonicalName());
    sh.setInitParameter(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, HelloRESTService.class.getPackage().getName());

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setSecurityHandler(basicAuth("admin", "adminpwd", "Private!"));
    context.setContextPath("/rest");
    context.addServlet(sh, "/*");
    context.addFilter(MyFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    final Server server = new Server();

    final ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setHost("172.18.133.20");
    connector.setPort(WEB_SERVER_PORT);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } finally {
        server.destroy();
    }

}

private static final SecurityHandler basicAuth(String username, String password, String realm) {

    HashLoginService hashLoginService = new HashLoginService();
    hashLoginService.putUser(username, Credential.getCredential(password), new String[]{"user"});
    hashLoginService.setName(realm);

    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setName(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user"});
    constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

    ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
    cm.setConstraint(constraint);
    cm.setPathSpec("/*");

    ConstraintSecurityHandler csh = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
    csh.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
    csh.setRealmName("myrealm");
    csh.addConstraintMapping(cm);
    csh.setLoginService(hashLoginService);

    return csh;

}

public static final class MyFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        //nothing to init
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://172.18.133.20:" + RESTClientStarter.WEB_SERVER_PORT);
        httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //nothing to destroy
    }
}

@Path("/test")
public static class HelloRESTService {

    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

}

Client code:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://172.18.133.20:8888/rest/test/hello",
        type : "GET",
        timeout : 120000,
        async : true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("admin:adminpwd")
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $("#container").text(error);
        },
        success: function(xhr) {
            $("#container").text(xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

Client code run on http://172.18.133.20:9999

Here is the full sources:

https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_apanasevich/cors/src

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problen excluding OPTIONS request from SecurityMapping. Just adding one line:

```
...
ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
cm.setMethod("GET"); //new line
cm.setConstraint(constraint);
cm.setPathSpec("/*");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://172.18.133.20:" + RESTClientStarter.WEB_SERVER_PORT);
and WEB_SERVER_PORT of your rest app is 9999 so httpResponse allow http://172.18.133.20:9999.
But you call it at port 8888 this is not allow.

Comment: No. REST app is running on 8888 port and client app is running on 9999 port

Comment: So, you should try httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://172.18.133.20"); instead of httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://172.18.133.20:" + RESTClientStarter.WEB_SERVER_PORT);

Comment: Why? Origin of ajax reuest is  http://172.18.133.20:9999. I've tried your decision but it doesn't works.

Comment: because if you write 172.18.133.20, your server is allow all request from this ip or you can write * for allow all request from any ip/domain. And you should add X-PINGOTHER into Access-Control-Allow-Headers, because server should be allow all method it can run.